# Insert shapefile features into PostgreSQL database using java EE (pragmatically)

Tags: shapefile, postgresql, geojson, java

I am working with PostgreSQL 9.4 and Java EE. I want to insert shapefile or layer's features into PostgreSQL, is there any solution so I can insert the whole shapefile into the database? OS is Windows 10.

I have successfully inserted one point into my database (PostgreSQL) table but I want all the features like: polygon, multi-polygon, marker etc.

Whatever I draw on the map should be stored into particular table of DB. I am getting all the features but unable to store them. How I can do this?

```
    try
    {   Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, password);
        sql=conn.createStatement();
        result1 = "insert into test(feature) values(ST_GeomFromText("+data+"))";
        result1 = "insert into test(feature,lat,lan) values(ST_GeomFromText('"+feature+"),"+lat+","+lan+"')";
        result1 = "insert into test(feature) values(ST_GeomFromText('POINT("+lat+" "+lan+")', 4326))";
        result1 = "insert into test(feature) values(ST_GeomFromText('"+feature+"("+lat+" "+lan+")'))";
        sql.executeUpdate(result1);
        out.println("data inserted...");

        String nextJSP = "/index.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);

        out.println("forwarding...");
        //System.out.println(fst);
    }   
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

### [image]

Getting table data and project it on map:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<%
JSONObject GJson = (JSONObject) request.getAttribute("geoJson");
//String GJson = (String)request.getAttribute("geoJson");
System.out.println("data at jsp : "+GJson);
%> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var geojson = <%= GJson%>
console.log(JSON.stringify(geojson));
var map = L.map('map');
//var geoJsonData = GeoJSON.parse(json);
var jsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
console.log(map.hasLayer(jsonLayer));
jsonLayer.addData(geojson); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please **edit** the question to clarify the meaning of "insert the whole shapefile" (do you mean as a BLOB or the *features* of the shapefile),  Your definition of "layer" is also unclear. Note that coding questions here at GIS SE are expected to contain code.

Comment: Is your use case different from using the shp2pgsql command line tool?

Comment: The command line for laoding the shapefile is:  shp2pgsql -I -s <SRID> <PATH/TO/SHAPEFILE> <SCHEMA>.<DBTABLE> | psql -U postgres -d <DBNAME>
The task is same but i have to do this using java code @til_b

Comment: Does calling the shp2pgsql command from java (using java.io.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) or similar) help you?

Comment: @til_b I edited the code in my question hope it will clear my need. right now I'm successfully getting the shapefile data in Geojson format and that data i have to put into DB(postgresql 9.4).

Comment: @nathansnider edited my question help me.

Comment: @Azimo please see this and help me

Comment: @til_b please see my code and help me where I'm leaking.

Comment: How are you unable to store? I can't see where your code is trying anything with a shapefile or features. Also, insert into spatial_ref_sys should normally not be necessary, as spatial_ref_sys is a meta table that stores spatial reference systems, unless you want to define your own SRS you should not need to do anything with that table. Please create a minimal example (maybe without the jsp parts) that clearly and completely shows what you are doing and why and where it fails. By creating this, you'll probably see where it fails yourself.

Comment: I have to draw features(point,line,etc) on map and that features should me permanently inserted into that table from I am getting the data and project it on leaflet map so when ever i reopen it it should show me all the newly added features along with old. Although i am getting data that code i am adding in question. please help me

Comment: "Getting table data" is working perfectly and it gives projection as output, now i have one doubt how i can store new drawen features in that table and which other files dbf, shp, shx what ever etc i should take care @til_b

Comment: Is there getBound() or any other method so I can send data(polygon,point etc) into PostgreSQL. Please any one help me.